# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread - Android

Tags: android, email, background

Hi I am developing an android application where I face this error when I try to send Email from my app. I am sending mail at the background without using intent based on [this link](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Send-Mail-in-Android-without-Using-Intent)

My program:

```
String em[] = {gete(u, e)};

MailSender sender = new GMailSender(
                "email id",
                "password");


                           sender.sendMail("Sub", "Body", "from address",""+em[0]);

                           move();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            }).start();
        }
    });
```

Application works fine when I specify the recipient's email address directly. 
Problem comes when I specify it as string array where I stored recipients email addresses.

Logcat shows :

> Skipped 222 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Can anyone tell me what is the exact problem ?

Comment: Yes, I found by using AsyncTask this can be solved. I don't have any idea how that should be used here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it is said to you, you're doing too much things. So use a thread to execute your send action:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sender.sendMail("Sub", "Body", "from address",""+em[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and still same thing shows in logcat, unable to send mail

Comment: Hey sorry  its working.. Thank you so much. I was checking the wrong mail id

Comment: I sure would like to see the .start();